# Passing an additional parameter to a function called using beast::bind_front_handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I have a `boost::beast` REST client. the `.hpp` and `.cxx` are given below.

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;


// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class RESTClient : public std::enable_shared_from_this<RESTClient> {

public:
    explicit RESTClient(net::io_context& ioc);

    virtual ~RESTClient();

    virtual void run(char const* host, char const* port, char const* target, int version);

    virtual void onResolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results);

    virtual void onConnect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type);

    virtual void onWrite(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

    virtual void onRead(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

private:
    void createGetRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version);

    void createPostRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version, char const *body);

    std::string createBody();

    tcp::resolver m_resolver;
    beast::tcp_stream m_stream;
    beast::flat_buffer m_buffer; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::string_body> m_httpRequest;
    http::response<http::string_body> m_httpResponse;
};



#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "RESTClient.hpp"

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}


RESTClient::RESTClient(net::io_context& ioc)
    : m_resolver(net::make_strand(ioc)), m_stream(net::make_strand(ioc)) {

}

RESTClient::~RESTClient() = default;


void RESTClient::run(char const* host, char const* port, char const* target, int version) {

    createPostRequest(host, target, version, createBody().c_str());

    m_resolver.async_resolve(host, port, beast::bind_front_handler(
        &RESTClient::onResolve,
        shared_from_this()));
}

void RESTClient::onResolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "resolve");
    }

    std::cout << "onResolve ******" << std::endl;
    m_stream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    m_stream.async_connect(results, beast::bind_front_handler(
        &RESTClient::onConnect,
        shared_from_this()));
}

void
RESTClient::onConnect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type) {
    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "connect");
    }

    std::cout << "onConnect ******" << std::endl;

    m_stream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    http::async_write(m_stream, m_httpRequest,
                      beast::bind_front_handler(
                          &RESTClient::onWrite,
                          shared_from_this()));
}

void
RESTClient::onWrite(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "write");
    }

    std::cout << "onWrite ******" << std::endl;

    http::async_read(m_stream, m_buffer, m_httpResponse, beast::bind_front_handler(
        &RESTClient::onRead,
        shared_from_this()));
}

void RESTClient::onRead(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {

    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "read");
    }

    std::cout << "onRead ******" << std::endl;

    std::cout << m_httpResponse << std::endl;


    m_stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

    if (ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected) {
        return fail(ec, "shutdown");
    }
}

void RESTClient::createGetRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version) {
    m_httpRequest.version(version);
    m_httpRequest.method(http::verb::get);
    m_httpRequest.target(target);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::host, host);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
}


void RESTClient::createPostRequest(char const* host, char const* target, int version, char const* body) {
    m_httpRequest.version(version);
    m_httpRequest.method(http::verb::post);
    m_httpRequest.target(target);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::host, host);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::content_length, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(strlen(body)));
    m_httpRequest.set(http::field::body, body);
    m_httpRequest.prepare_payload();
}


std::string RESTClient::createBody() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
    boost::property_tree::read_json("test.json",tree);
    std::basic_stringstream<char> jsonStream;
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(jsonStream, tree, false);
    std::cout << "json stream :" << jsonStream.str() << std::endl;
    return jsonStream.str();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 4 && argc != 5) {
        std::cerr <<
                  "Usage: http-client-async <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n" <<
                  "Example:\n" <<
                  "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 /\n" <<
                  "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const target = argv[3];
    int version = argc == 5 && !std::strcmp("1.0", argv[4]) ? 10 : 11;

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;
    std::cout << "version: " << version << std::endl;

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<RESTClient>(ioc)->run(host, port, target, version);

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the get operation is complete.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to pass an additional parameter of the type `std::function<void(bool)>` to `onWrite` in the line shown below.

```
http::async_write(m_stream, m_httpRequest,
                      beast::bind_front_handler(
                          &RESTClient::onWrite,
                          shared_from_this()));
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The declaration:

```
virtual void onWrite(std::function<void(bool)> f, beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
```

The definition:

```
void
RESTClient::onWrite(std::function<void(bool)> f, beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec) {
        return fail(ec, "write");
    }
    //...
```

The invocation:

```
http::async_write(m_stream, m_httpRequest,
                  beast::bind_front_handler(
                      &RESTClient::onWrite,
                      shared_from_this(), 
                      [](bool){ std::cout << "functor" << std::endl;}
                     ));
```